# IF I click one cell email or name needs to be captured in Gsheet

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

if someone clicks on the column Ay checkbox his/her email needs to be captured in a different column cell

[[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not always going to be able to get access to user and the only trigger that works on a click is onSelectionChange() which is a simple trigger which means it can't do anything that requires permissions and Session.getActiveUser() requires `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`.  I don't think there is a solution for what you want.

You can try this function to see if it can work for you.

```
  function onSelectionChange(e) {
  if (e.user) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Log");//You need to create this
    sh.appendRow([new Date(),e.user.email,e.user.nickname])
    Logger.log('email: %s', e.user.email);
    Logger.log('nickName: %s', e.user.nickname);
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Trying it on yourself doesn't count.

#### Using installable onedit function:

```
function onInstallableEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");//debug
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//debug
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Audit sheet May" && e.range.columnStart == 51 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == 1 ) {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');//debug
    if(e.user) {
      //e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(`${e.user.email}\n${new Date()}`);
      e.range.offset(0,1,1,2).setValues([[e.user.email,new Date()]]);
    }
  }
}

function createTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onInstallableEdit").length == 0)  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onInstallableEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: getSheetByName("Log") do i need to mention my sheet name here

Comment: Could you please help me my sheet name "Audit sheet May",and if any one click on AW2 cell then  AZ2  user ID or name need to be captured .Please create the script for me

Comment: Please provide more detail information regarding your script.

Comment: Please refer the picture which I have attached I have Added check box in column AY and access has been given to multiple users ,my requirement is if any user ticked the check box  his/her username or email id needs to be capture in a different cell .I.E if you click AY2 check box then your email id need to Capture in AZ2 cell

Comment: So it look like you need to use onEdit trigger for that.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: I have already set value ticked =1 or non ticked =0

Comment: Thanks for the ticked value.  I needed to know that. By default it is "TRUE", which is what I was assuming

Comment: I set up a testbed and it is working now

Comment: Still not working I have to run both the script right ? do I need any change in the script  if it possible I want the cell need to capture the user ID/Email id with date

Comment: You only need to run the creatTrigger script once.  Their is no user id there is just the email.  If you wish a date there is new Date()

Comment: Could you please add the date same

Comment: what's the point if you can't get what you have now running?

Comment: Okay now you have the email and the date.  Can you get it to run?

Comment: But the Email ID & Date captured in which cell I think this is not mentioned

Comment: I put in the same cell because you did not specify.  You can change it to whatever you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much now it is working fine,you are the genius please help me only  Email ID and date & time in different different cell.I.E Email ID need to capture next Cell Column 52 and date need to capture in column 53

Comment: Now they're in different columns

Comment: Thank you so much ! you are really a genius, I want to learn Appscript  do you have any PDF or link for that so that I can Refer

Comment: Just Google `google apps script`